# R language: Replace variables if the value can be matched in another table

Tags: r

I have a sales report table (DF1)and I need to replace only a few product codes by their associated group codes

```
       Model        SOLD
        A             5
        B             4
        C             4
        D             3
        F             11
```

I have another table (DF2) where I have the Model# and the associated group codes

```
       Model        Group
        A             1
        B             1
        C             2
        D             2
```

I would like to replace the model# in DF1 by the group number if the model exist in DF2.

The  wanted end result:

```
       Model        SOLD
        1             5
        1             4
        2             4
        2             3
        F             11
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [qdapTools](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qdapTools/index.html)'s `lookup` family, specifically, the binary operator `%lc+%` (a wrapper for the `data.table` package).  The `l` stands for `lookup`, the `c` forces te terms to `character` and the `+` only replaces those elements that are found in the lookup table:

```
library(qdap)
df1$Model <- df1$Model %lc+% df2
```

Here it is more explicitly:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Model = structure(1:5, .Label = c("A", "B", "C", 
    "D", "F"), class = "factor"), SOLD = c(5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 11L)), .Names = c("Model", 
    "SOLD"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

df2 <- structure(list(Model = structure(1:4, .Label = c("A", "B", "C", 
    "D"), class = "factor"), Group = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("Model", 
    "Group"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

library(qdap)
df1$Model <- df1$Model %lc+% df2

df1

##   Model SOLD
## 1     1    5
## 2     1    4
## 3     2    4
## 4     2    3
## 5     F   11
```